# Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SN,SUM(QTY) FROM SP GROUP BY SN HAVING SUM(QTY)>(SELECT AVG(SUM(QTY)) FROM (SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM SP GROUP BY SN ))
```

Now I get the error:

> "Every derived table must have its own alias".

Comment: Error messages in MySQL are unusally helpful. If a derived table wants or needs an alias, give it one! :-)

Comment: What happened when, as suggested by the error code, you gave the derived table its own alias ? Or did you fail to follow the instructions given by the error code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says you have to name every derived table.

Try the following:

```
SELECT SN, SUM(QTY)
FROM SP
GROUP BY SN
HAVING SUM(QTY) > (
    SELECT AVG(z)
    FROM (
      SELECT SUM(QTY) z
      FROM SP
      GROUP BY SN
      ) a
    )
```